# How can I get everything going threw the device audioPlayer in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get every thing going threw the audio player in my flutter app. Exactly the same way than when you are connected in bluetooth in your car. If you are on youtube, your car will display video's name and play it threw the speaker. If you change to spotify, it will also change, even if you go threw local music file.

Does anyone got an idea about how to do this ?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the AVPlayer which is the native player of iOS.

In Flutter you can get the following library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_playout

This library provides the Player in notification center and on lockscreen and is hihgly customizable. I recommend you using this and change it to your fits.

P.s: It also provides native android player.

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look !

Comment: Have you ever used it ? I Stuggle trying to use the exemple, the AudioPlayout class is not inside any of the package